# Изменить размер шрифта WebView

Tags: android

Можно ли изменить размер шрифта, в WebView настройками или программно? Желательно способ через изменение атрибутов. Мне нужно на телефонах, и на планшетах разные размеры шрифта установить

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694306/how-to-set-text-size-in-webview-in-android), может найдется то, что вам подойдёт

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы увеличить используйте эти варианты:

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() + 10);
```

или

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
```

и чтобы уменьшить обратное действие:

```
settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() - 10);
```

или

```
settings.setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER);
```

Вот все варианты размеров:

```
WebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLEST); 
WebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER); 
WebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.NORMAL); 
WebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.BIGGER); 
WebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.BIGGEST);
```